# Excel Vba export word to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

I've been struggling to get a conversion of word files to PDFS (Ran using excel) to work.

I've tried the below(From other answers on here) and get the error(On the ExportAsFixedFormat Line), "Invalid procedure call or argument":

```
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Test.docx"
objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\test.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
objWord.Quit
```

I've also tried this setup however this doesn't error when ran, but the PDFs error when trying to open.

```
Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Test.docx"
    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\Test.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    objWord.Quit
```

Comment: Which line causes the error in the first code snippet? Is there an error when trying to open a PDF produced by the second?

Comment: In the first snippet: objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\test.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF 

And yeah the second one is when trying to open.